# Functional equation by me!

Tags: mathematics, functional-equation

Find all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$f(x)f(x+y)=xf(x)+f\big(f(x)\big)f(y)$$
for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$.

---

Source: Problem by me.

Comment: This is more strictly a math olympiad question rather than a puzzle.  There is no appropriate site for such creations as of yet, so it is better suited somewhere else.

Comment: @greenturtle3141 There was a significance amount of functional equations (7) which was posted. It is on-topic, or else others has been closed already.

Comment: That's a *non sequitur*. Plenty of off-topic questions remain open, because they have not been brought to the attention of the community or there is not a significant need to remove them.

Comment: @Nij, these are not math textbook style.

Comment: What.. this is exactly a textbook question. That you thought it up independently, like many writers do with questions, doesn't change that.

Comment: @Nij, this is a Math Olympiad style problem, way far than math textbook kind of problem.

Comment: That comment makes no sense.

Comment: @Nij I am asking this on meta, and have a vote.

Comment: @Nij This question is very clearly on topic. Textbook problems are mostly those where you can just follow an algorithm to solve it. This is a maths puzzle that requires you to think outside the box. I'd argue that most Math Olympiad questions are more puzzles than problems. https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/are-math-textbook-style-problems-on-topic/2784#2784

Comment: @Nij You might want to understand better what's meant by "maths textbook question" [in the context of this site's scope](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2784/5373). Not everything that "could be found in some textbook somewhere" is automatically off-topic. If I write a textbook and fill it with PSE maths puzzles, can we then go and close them all? No, of course not - it's about **the nature of the question**, like whether it's a rote arithmetic problem or involves some thinking outside the box.

Comment: There's very little thinking outside the box involved for this one, in contrast to many textbook questions that do have it (the "trick" here is to fix easy numbers first and then reduce by forcing, which is not outside a sensible mathematics approach for solving the problem). If that's enough to make it a puzzle, there are entire tests that can be considered puzzles, yet posting them would be heavily opposed. I don't say it's off-topic merely because it could be in a textbook (which is a ludicrous interpretation to assign), I think it off-topic because it isn't fundamentally different from...

Comment: ... asking *after looking in two boxes, one person saying the left is double the right, less one, while someone else says the right is triple the left-less-one. How can this be true?* This is a simple algebraic problem that I will be using in my own classes - the only "trick" is to recognise where the brackets fit and solve accordingly. Does that make it a puzzle? Seems so, according to the same meta post you provided, merely on a different level. @Randal'Thor

Comment: @Nij "very little thinking outside the box" what do you think does have enough thinking outside the box? Do you think puzzles that have sensible solutions are not puzzles?

Comment: I think that using a straightforward mathematical tool isn't thinking outside the box. Having a sensible solution doesn't make a difference to whether something is a puzzle or a textbook problem, both should have answers that make sense (otherwise they're just "guess the number I'm thinking of" pranks). @mypronounismonicareinstate

Comment: @Nij: Not trying to defend the quality of my solution, but I can say for sure that what I wrote in my answer only included half the things I tried. I agree that no particular step requires anything beyond basic algebra, but finding the correct sequence of steps was non-trivial, at least for me. Maybe I should have written it better, but I absolutely did have a bit of "aha" once I struck on the correct path.

Comment: I'm not saying it's not a neat solution either, but "having a neat solution" doesn't make a difference in whether the problem itself is actually a puzzle nor does "there are several possible approaches", as some appear to be arguing here and elsewhere.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The set of functions which satisfy the functional equation is:

> the all zero function and the identity function. Let $g$ be a function satisfying the relationship, and first let $x=y=0$. Then we have $$g(0)^2 = 0 + g(g(0)) \times g(0)$$ This implies either $g(0) = 0$ or $g(g(0)) = g(0)$.

In either case:

> $\lambda = g(0)$ is a fixed point of $g$, or in other words $g(\lambda) = \lambda$. Let $x=\lambda$ and $y=0$, in which case we have $$g(\lambda)g(\lambda) = \lambda g(\lambda) + g(g(\lambda))g(0)$$ This gives the equality $$\lambda^2 = 2\lambda^2$$ which forces $\lambda = 0$.

With this knowledge:

> let $x$ be any real and let $y=0$. This forces $$g(x)^2 = xg(x)$$ for all real $x$, which implies either $g(x) = 0$ or $g(x) = x$ for all real $x$. This implies either $g$ is the zero function, which one can easily check satisfies the condition above, or there exists $\mu \neq 0$ such that $g(\mu) = \mu$.

Finally:

> Let $y$ be any real such that $g(y) = 0$. Then we have $$g(\mu)g(\mu+y) = \mu g(\mu) + g(g(\mu))g(y)$$ which implies $\mu g(\mu+y) = \mu^2$ and thus $g(\mu+y) = \mu$ since $\mu \neq 0$. Since $\mu \neq 0$ this forces $\mu + y = \mu$, which forces $y=0$. Thus $g(x) = x$ for all real $x$ and $g$ is the identity function. Again it is easy to check this satisfies the condition above.